# How to getting data from mobile analytics.??

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mobile-analytics

i used KPI for getting data from aws mobile analytics using follwing KPI url :

https://mobileanalytics.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2014-06-05/apps 
but problem is when my account is login is give me data. but when i logout from aws account this url give me response **This site can’t be reached**.
how to fix this issue. 
this is article i use to getting data in mobile analytics result. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobileanalytics/latest/ug/drs-getting-apps.html
please help me if you have any idea about it. otherwise give me different way to getting data from aws mobile analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Hi what language are you using to make the KPI requests?
It sounds like you are not handling the sig v4 signing. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html